# Reducing database access when same query on multiple similar objects

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have an operation in one of my views

```
order_details = [order.get_order_details() for order in orders]
```

Now `order.get_order_details()` runs one database query. So for current situation. Depending on size of `orders` the number of database access will be huge.

Before having to use cache, is there anything that can speed this up?

Is it possible to merge all the select operations into one single database operation?

Will making it an atomic transaction using `transaction.atomic()` increase any performance? because technically the query will be sent at once instead of individually, right?

Edit: is there any design changes/ pattern that will avoid this situation?

Edit:

```
def get_order_details(self):
    items = Item.objects.filter(order=self)
    item_list = [item.serialize for item in items]
    return {
        'order_details': self.serialize,
        'item_list': item_list
    }
```

Comment: You want [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or perhaps `prefetch_related` (just below)

Comment: Oh, then we're going to need to see what `get_order_details` looks like. My only other guess is to use the `__in` operator. I can't do better than guess with so little information.

Comment: I am sorry I had misunderstood you previous comment. I thought you said about using select_related on order. I think it can be solved by it. Thank you:) Please put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Transactions will not send all queries at once. You still perform individual queries. Now, transactions do have some performance benefits, but not nearly as much as the benefits of performing just a single database roundtrip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `orders` is a `QuerySet`, e.g. the result of `Order.objects.filter(...)`, add:

```
.prefetch_related(Prefetch('item_set'))
```

to the end of the query. Then use:

```
items = self.item_set
```

in `get_order_details`.

See the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: Item is a Model with Foreign Key to Order. Will this still work?

Comment: @SidhinThomas that is what I assumed, so I think so. By the way I made a typo in case you already copied code, it's `self.item_set` not `self.items_set`.

Comment: It's much more elegant solution that to use `select_related` on `Item` and retrieving the details which I just implemented. Thank you